# How can I multiply two linked lists into a third list?

Tags: java, parsing, data-structures, illegalargumentexception

The function takes two integers as strings, let's say "123" and "456", which are parsed into their own linked lists in consecutive order. Hence first will be 3 -> 2 -> 1 and the second 6 -> 5 -> 4.

I have these linked lists initialized, but how do I multiply them to achieve the product 123 * 456? I have no clue how to approach this, especially because they are parsed in the opposite order.

I am NOT allowed to edit these linked lists. I can however, parse them into two dummy lists.

Any help is appreciated.

```
public static BigInteger multiply(BigInteger first, BigInteger second) {

        /* IMPLEMENT THIS METHOD */

        // following line is a placeholder for compilation
        return null;
    }

// where earlier in the class

public BigInteger() {
        negative = false;
        numDigits = 0;
        front = null;
    }

// and in the same package

public class DigitNode {

    int digit;
    DigitNode next;

    DigitNode(int digit, DigitNode next) {
        this.digit = digit;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return digit + "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Broad question, so I'll give a broad answer: K A R A T S U B A

Comment: Does this work even when first and second are objects with linked lists?

Comment: God knows, but Godspeed

Comment: [This page](https://brilliant.org/wiki/karatsuba-algorithm/) has an example of how to do Karatsuba with base-10 numbers. I'd highly suggest just using naive multiplication algorithm to test if your multiplication is working at all, though.

Comment: Are you allowed to use data structures?

Comment: Given that the linked list stores the number least significant digit first, isn't this just how you would multiply by hand? `3 * 6 = 18` carry the `1`, rinse and repeat?

Answer (score 2):

Think of how you do multiplication by hand:

```
          456
        x 123
        -----
         1368
      +  9120
      + 45600
     --------
        56088
```

With your lists, `3->2->1` and `6->5->4`, you multiply 3 and 6, giving you a product of 18. Then you multiply 3 and 5, for a product of 15. But you have to multiply that by 10 because the digit `5` is in the second position. Then multiply 3 and 4 to give you 12, which you multiply by 100. So the sequence is:

```
3*6 = 18
3*5*10 = 150
3*4*100 = 1200
```

Sum those to get 1368.

Then you start over with the 2. But it's in the second position, so it's actually 20:

```
10*2*6 = 120
10*2*5*10 = 1000
10*2*4*100 = 8000
             ----
             9120
```

And repeat with the third number, 1:

```
100*1*6 = 600
100*1*5*10 = 5000
100*1*4*100 = 40000
              -----
              45600
```

Add up your partials (45600+9120+1368) = 56088

You can do this with two nested loops that iterate over your linked lists. It looks something like this:

```
total = 0
l1 = list1.head
l1Multiplier = 1
while l1 != null
    l2 = list2.head
    l2Multiplier = 1
    l1Sum = 0
    while l2 != null
        prod = l1Multiplier * l1.data * l2.data * l2Multiplier
        l1Sum = l1Sum + prod
        l2Multiplier = l2Multiplier * 10
        l2 = l2.next
    end while
    total = total + l1Sum
    l1Multiplier = l1Multiplier * 10
end while

// at this point, the result is in the total variable.
// You can extract the digits into another linked list.
```

That's not the most efficient way, but I suspect that the goal here isn't to come up with the most efficient algorithm, but rather to learn how to iterate over linked lists.

If you're interested in a much more efficient algorithm, check out the [Karatsuba algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm).